Git symlinks on a filesystem without symlinks
I need to work with git in git-bash on a Win10 box without admin rights. The filesystem doesn't allow me to create symbolic link with ln in git-bash nor mklink in powershell. Is there a way to add symlinks to the git repository? Any pitfalls I need to avoid with this combination of symlinks + FS without symlinks?

To add a symbolic link to a repository, you can use these low-level commands:
# make a file with the link target
printf "%s" target/of/link > the_link

# add the object to the database and get its OID (SHA1)
ln_s_obj=$(git hash-object -w the_link)

# add the OID as a symbolic link to the index
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 120000 $ln_s_obj the_link

This represents the symbolic link as a text file in the file system. The use of printf ensures that there is no LF or CRLF at the end of the file. You cannot use echo.
Side note: The method would also work on a filesystem that actually understands symbolic links. But then you must mark the repository accordingly:
git config core.symlinks false

Otherwise, the next git status will tell that the file type changed from symbolic link to a file. This setting is the default on Windows.
One pitfall is to expect that such an entry works like a symbolic link. It does not, of course.
